# Remove submenu item in TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, menu, tinymce

I'm trying to remove a subitem from a TinyMCE dropdown toolbar button in WordPress.

The button is a plugin button (TinyMCE Table Button), and it inserts an item that allows the user to do CSS styling on the tables.

[image: TinyMCE plugin generated dropdown]

(*Taulukon ominaisuudet* == *Table properties*)

The toolbar button is created with

```
editor.addButton("table", {
    type: "menubutton",
    title: "Table",
    menu: menuItems
});
```

The menu item is created with

```
editor.addMenuItem('tableprops', {
    text: 'Table properties',
    context: 'table',
    onPostRender: postRender,
    onclick: dialogs.tableProps
});
```

`editor` is the TinyMCE plugins constructor param:

```
define("tinymce/tableplugin/Plugin", [
    "tinymce/tableplugin/TableGrid",
    ...
    "tinymce/PluginManager"
], function(TableGrid, Quirks, CellSelection, Dialogs, Tools, TreeWalker, Env, PluginManager) {
    var each = Tools.each;

    function Plugin(editor) {
        var clipboardRows, self = this, dialogs = new Dialogs(editor);

        ...
```

The editor has a function for `addMenuItem`, but I can't find anything similar to `removeMenuItem`. I also tried to find the menu item inside the editor so I could remove it by hand, but the system is a bit shady as to where the buttons and menus are.

Is there a logical way of removing menu items in TinyMCE or will I have to remove it directly from the DOM after the editor has been generated?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Just realize, you are using a different table plugin.  I guess an easy way is to inspect the element/source and get the element ID of that menu item and use CSS to hide it.

```
<style>
#mceu_38 {display:none !important;}
</style>
```

Below is my original response, it is meant for editing the default menu bars

---

You can customize the menu bar in the init function:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menu : { // this is the complete default configuration
        file   : {title : 'File'  , items : 'newdocument'},
        edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
        insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
        view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid'},
        format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
        table  : {title : 'Table' , items : 'inserttable deletetable | cell row column'},
        tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'spellchecker code'}
    },    
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

Just remove the items you don't want in each menu property.

Here's an example with Table Properties removed:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/43eaab

Here's the documentation: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:menu

gl.

Comment: Yeah, it is a third party plugin, as WordPress doesn't include the table functionalities out of the box. I'd rather not use direct `#id { display: none; }` hiding as the ID could change randomly. Currently I've settled on parsing and removing all table properties using PHP `preg_replace` when outputting the HTML itself. Thanks for the `init` tip, I'll see whether I can get anything out of it.

Comment: Just curious, which plugin are you using for the table functionality?

Comment: In the WP repo its called just *TinyMCE Table Button* unless I'm horribly wrong.

Comment: That might be the built-in plugin for table buttons.  http://www.tinymce.com/.  Check that table toolbar item.  You should be able to disable it if you can locate the init function.

Comment: Well the UI looks just like it apart from the textual dropdown button! I'll have to see if WP itself has some hooks for the menu generation in the `init` method.

Comment: NOTE: When setting up the menu item you can add a custom id to explicitly set the item that you want to hide using css.  tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'spellchecker code', id: 'ToolsId'}